# How To Dual Boot Ubuntu And Linux Mint

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot

Ok so I have ubuntu 13.04 and today I installed linux mint 15 alongside ubuntu by partitioning the hard drive in the setup. But now when I start my computer, it automatically boots to ubuntu with no options.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a second install puts its boot loader into the MBR.

If still booting Ubuntu run this and see if it adds Mint to grub menu.

```
sudo update-grub
```

If not run Boot-Repair and post link to BootInfo report.

Post the link to the BootInfo report that this creates. Is part of Boot-Repair:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair