# 1 HD 1 SSD, after installing Ubuntu on /sdb Linux Mint on /sda1 is not in the UEFI/Bios though sda2 and sda3 are ? is this recoverable if so how?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Seems to me installing Ubuntu on `sdb` after 1st installing Linux Mint on `sda` should have had no effect on it, am disappointed as spent time configuring the Linux mint, guess I can go reinstall, but wouldn't want it to NOW mess up Ubuntu on `sdb`, sigh.

Actually in the Bios/UEFI it shows 2 "Ubuntu" both on the SSD, and doesn't show the HD , so it is like I'm booting off the SSD which has / had Linux mint, but it boots the HD which has "Ubuntu" ....

Restating: in the Boot Options I see only the SSD (/sda) "SATA3_1"( I see SATA3_1: SanDisk SDS; ubuntu (SATA3_1: Sandisk SDS) and another duplicate of the latter option, nothing for the HD where I installed Ubuntu(though it boots to  the HD) , as if Ubuntu install on /sdb, wrote the MBR to /sda  is that possible?

#### Edit 1:

hmm, i now see this : [How To Dual Boot Ubuntu And Linux Mint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328674/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-and-linux-mint)
`update-grub` in ubuntu  did not fix anything so guess i'll try boot repair, sigh

#### Edit 2:

Well that post is circa 2011, off USB booted and ran boot repair, 1-click doesn't fix it, and the pastebin link is generic, nothing uploads, further, I do see an option to "place the boot flag on sda1 sda2 etc
however, I fear to use it,  as I don't want to fix  Linux Mint only to break Ubuntu....

#### Edit 3

```
fdisk -l 
Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   2050047    999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2050048 234440703 232390656 110.8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt


Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624   2050047    999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  2050048 625141759 623091712 297.1G Linux filesystem
```

#### boot-info (partial)

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System: 
Boot files:        /EFI/ubuntu/fbx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
                   /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
                   /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext2
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
Operating System: 
Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg
```

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       crypto_LUKS
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info:
```

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System: 
Boot files:
```

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
Operating System: 
Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg
```

EDIT 4:
OK, I've read your excellent, considered replies, and I'm impressed with the level of time and assistance provided. thx, so, my update is this: I gave up and reinstall Linux Mint to the SSD /sda  ;  Now, if I wanted to install Ubuntu onto /sdb      (like changing to Xubuntu), what if I just disconnected the SSD and leave the 2nd HD  on /sdb  and installed Xubuntu to it,  would I still have this same problem?   eg  after installing Xubuntu to /sdb  I then reconnected  the SSD to /sda ??

I don't really have the time, to sort out  why this breaks, though I generally understand what your saying, I am just as likely to break the systems as fix them , as I'm not at your folks level of tweaking :) ;  THAT or I just don't install a Ubuntu based system on   /sdb  ;  like I could just install Fedora on it (in fact I had Fedora on /sdb  but it has it's own issues, or maybe you could suggest something else for /sdb  that doesn't require me to learn  Grub  and MBR speak ??

Now I guess, though, I am stuck with these multiple  "ubuntu"  choices in the UEFI to boot order,  and if I accidentally re-chose  the "ubuntu" on /sdb, I might be screwed again ....sigh

EDIT 5
oldfred, yes the 1st install of LMint had an encrypted drive.  The 2nd install Ubuntu, was also encypted onto /sdb , from there I'm pretty much lost on what your saying exactly. At this point, see my 4th edit, i've reinstalled LMint onto /sda  and I am unsure how to proceed any further, LMint is now fine and booting, the BIOS  has two identical looking options in boot order, actually it has 3  2 says ubuntu,  1 just says  SSD, .....I am assuming if I change to the other 'ubuntu' it will boot 'ubuntu' standard edition, and in all probability mess up my now, fine, functioning Linux Mint install;   given my choice,  I'd like to now reinstall  Xubuntu onto the 2nd HD , where regular Ubuntu is now,  I had been told to manual edit the partitions and do somthing called 'alongside' this time/the next time,   however, I sort of doubt that I'd do that correctly, my other thought, is to remove the SSD from the SATA header, and install xubuntu onto sdb  and let it auto partition, then reattach the SSD onto /sda  and hopefully I could boot either    the sda or the sdb  and not have any issues ......but again, I am fearful of breaking Linux mint again, to which I've spend many hours again configuring to my needs ... any feedback further very welcome....... :)

Comment: Are you able to see grub at the start? and what do you mean by installing Ubuntu on sdb? Did you give location for grub on sda or sdb?

Comment: can you update your partition details from live usb? Have you chosen alongside option for installing ubuntu?

Comment: hunch,  both "ubuntu" listings in the Bios  boot Ubuntu, but one stops and asks me which version I want,    re: sdb : 1st I installed Linux Mint  on the SSD which is /sda  ;  I had Mint up and running,  then I went and installed Ubuntu on a 2nd  HD  which I'm calling  /sdb   ;  I just clicked thru, I didn't stop and do anything during the GUI partitioning etc

Comment: I'm not sure what "alongside option" is, so I guess not.  re: can I partition from a live usb,  perhaps I could if I knew what to do  and how

Comment: Personally I have never installed Mint and Ubuntu together but Installed windows and Ubuntu in dual boot.   When installing Ubuntu from a live USB it always ask for ´something else´  or ´alongside installation´ option. So it must have shown that. If you haven´t done manual partition then its not a ´something else´ option. Which link you followed for installing ubuntu? You can do almost everything from live usb. After booting from live usb please post the result to fdisk -l command.

Comment: Ubuntu still boots, so I guess I don't have to use live-usb  for everything, I do have the boot-info  as well, i posted fdisk -l above : I'll boot part of that also above

Comment: please post screenshot of the command

Comment: screenshot of boot-info  or fdisk ; i believe whats relevant for fdisk is already above .....

Comment: From the information I am not able to see boot disk. You can boot to Ubuntu, It looks like the boot order is correct. MBR is generally overwritten by last installed OS.(Whichever disk it may be on based on the first boot drive). you can try changing the order of boot disk. There is no harm, you can always change it back. If grub is not able to add Linux mint. try adding the entry manually to grub.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/81660/how-can-i-edit-my-grub-bootloader-entries-hide-rename-remove-preferably-doi

Comment: Next time when you make your system dual boot, use manual partitioning for each os. This way you will be able to track which OS is installed in which part and where grub is installed.

Comment: sorry, I get real confuse on MBR and booting vocabulary.  I had asked about this  " I do see an option to "place the boot flag on sda1"  using the utility boot-info ;  would that be something I want to do, place a "boot flag" ?........otherwise I'm not real clear how to proceed: how would I "change the order of boot disk"  or  "edit grub to add linux mint"  ??

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/562857/no-boot-loader-is-installed-in-the-mbr-of-dev-sda check this link. whether you have disabled secure boot or not and the continuation link also.

Comment: um, secure boot is/has been off,  i don't know what a continuation link is; i did add a 4th edit above today monday, not sure if i've already asked too much..... i could unplug the ssd, and install to the hd if that doesn't also end up breaking the ssd when i put it back on the machine?

Answer (score 1):

First, a broad comment: You're trying to apply BIOS-specific boot knowledge to an EFI-based computer. This practice more-or-less guarantees that you'll end up making mistakes, because BIOS and EFI boot processes are *very* different. In particular, you should stop thinking about "booting a disk" and think in EFI terms -- under EFI, the firmware boots a *file,* which resides on an [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) A single ESP can hold boot loaders for multiple OSes.

Now, your specific problem is a result of a couple of interacting factors:

- Unfortunately, because Mint is derived from Ubuntu but the Mint developers did not see fit to differentiate their version of GRUB (the Ubuntu/Mint boot loader), the boot loaders from the two distributions try to live in the same place. Thus, whichever one was installed most recently will take control of the boot process.
- Although each of your disks has its own ESP, the Ubuntu (and therefore the Mint) installer has [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379) that makes it use the first ESP it finds, even if it's not on the distribution's main disk or if you try to force it to use something else. Please click the link to the bug. If you have a Launchpad account, you can click the link to say it affects you, which will increase the bug's "heat" and make it a little more likely it will be fixed.

As a result of all of this, you have *one* GRUB installed (in `/dev/sda1`), and it's *currently* controlled through Mint -- but if and when a GRUB update comes down through Ubuntu, the control is likely to switch to Ubuntu. (This is what I call a "boot coup" -- see [my page on this subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) -- but with the added twist that both distributions are trying to write the same files.) If you subsequently update Mint's GRUB, control would switch back to Mint.

You *can* at least partially separate the two OSs' boot loaders:

1. In Mint, edit `/etc/fstab` so that it mounts the ESP from `/dev/sdb` rather than the ESP from `/dev/sda` to `/boot/efi`.
2. In Mint, unmount the ESP (`sudo umount /boot/efi`).
3. In Mint, mount the newly-adjusted ESP (`sudo mount -a`), and check with `df` to be sure the correct partition is mounted.
4. In Mint, re-install GRUB to the ESP (`sudo grub-install`, probably followed by `sudo update-grub`).
5. If you want Ubuntu to control the boot process, reboot into Ubuntu and type `sudo grub-install` (and maybe `sudo update-grub`) to give it control. (Alternatively, you could type `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see the current boot loader options and then adjust the boot order with `sudo efibootmgr -o #[,#,#...]`, but you'll need to figure out the numbers (`#`) for the order based on the `efibootmgr -v` output. Doing this will require identifying disks by partition GUID values.)
6. Be aware that boot coups are likely to happen in the future.

IMHO, though, GRUB is only a fair fit for your needs. The trouble is that GRUB's boot-time operation is far too dependent on preconfigured settings. That is, the GRUB menu is built by the `update-grub` script. This script is run after GRUB and kernel updates, but if you update the kernel on the OS that doesn't control GRUB, those updates will *not* appear in the GRUB menu until either you manually run `update-grub` in the OS that does control GRUB or until you update a kernel or GRUB in that OS. There's also the question of boot coups, which can be controlled (see my page on the subject), but it's easy to get confused about what's in control because the Ubuntu and Mint versions of GRUB look pretty much identical.

You might want to look into my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) as an alternative. Unlike GRUB, rEFInd scans for boot loaders and kernels at every boot, so it will pick up your kernels after they've been updated no matter which distribution you use to install rEFInd. You'd still have the potential for boot coups, but at least if one happens it would be obvious. Also, you'd probably need to do some reconfiguration, including running `mkrlconf` in the distribution you did *not* use to install rEFInd and perhaps editing `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf` to tweak some settings and hide the (probably now unwanted) GRUB entries.

Comment: It looks like sda install may be LVM (with encryption?) and other standard partitions. But if second install does not have LVM & encryption drivers (and mount of other encrypted install so unencrypted) then os-prober in second install cannot find an encrypted install which it should not unless you specifically allow it. To get Ubuntu to see different encrypted install:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lvm2 cryptsetup`  then mount/open your encrypted partition and run os-prober.